# Name for phenomenon where individual members disagree with their own collective action

Tags: political-philosophy, sociology

I was thinking about a phenomenon related to groupthink lately that I often observe. Frequently, social groups seem to collectively act or trend in ways the individual members consciously disagree with. As a simple example, consider how in many companies most people disagree with the corporate communication style but will talk in the exact same manner themselves.

I was wondering whether this is a phenomenon that has a name and is studied in sociology?

Comment: Perhaps [Asch Conformity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asch_conformity_experiments) or authoritarian followership.

Comment: [Conformity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformity)?

Comment: But some centuries ago such a behaviour was called [Nicodemite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicodemite).

Comment: The mentioned terms do not cover what I mean, because they imply some majority of the social group whose individual views align with the collective ones. I am referring to a situation in which the collective values are only held individually by only a minority of the community.

Comment: What you are describing sounds similar to the concept of *false compromise*. This occurs when parties to a collective decision agree to adopt a compromise position, but nobody actually prefers or agrees with the position agreed upon.

Comment: Re. "a situation in which the collective values are only held individually by only a minority". Sounds like an authoritarian situation then. The authoritarian leaders are the minority and the authoritarian followers are the compliant majority.  Evolved from tribal group psychology: basic instincts for tribal cohesion. e.g. Freud's [*Group Psychology*](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/35877/35877-h/35877-h.htm) is one of the earlier studies. A stimulating read.

Comment: I recommend moving this question to Psychology SE, as it appears to be a question about scientific terminology. If it's a question about English common use, I'd suggest moving it to English SE.

Comment: Since it doesn't cost me anything to mention - from your clarifying comments, I think you're looking for *agency capture* if the people setting the incentive structure which make people behave thus are a minority who prefers the outcome, or *perverse incentives* if the people setting the incentive structure thought they were working for different outcome from the one the incentive structure actually promotes.

Comment: I'd say: "normal"

Comment: *Dysfunctional*.

Comment: Thanks for the comments everyone. I've learned a lot. I do think that false consensus is the closest concept to what I envision, with agency capture an interesting related concept. I'm afraid I will have to somehow coin my own term for this, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word is silent dissent. Social groups operate as holistic entities with emergent properties that transcend the sum of their members. These groups may engage in collective actions or behaviors that reflect shared norms, values, and practices.
However, individual members retain their autonomy and subjective perspectives. Despite participating in collective actions, individuals may harbor dissenting opinions or preferences that diverge from the group consensus.

Group cohesion and conformity play significant roles in shaping collective behavior. Social pressure, norms, and expectations within a group can influence individuals to align their actions with the perceived consensus, even if they disagree.
The desire for social acceptance, fear of rejection, and the need to maintain harmony within the group may compel individuals to conform to collective norms and behaviors, even if they privately hold dissenting views.

There is dialectical tension between individuality and group identity, wherein individuals navigate between asserting their autonomy and affiliating with collective entities.
While individuals may maintain their unique perspectives and values, they also seek belongingness and validation within social groups. This tension can manifest in situations where individuals compromise their dissenting views to maintain group cohesion or avoid conflict.

Cognitive dissonance theory suggests that individuals experience psychological discomfort when their beliefs or behaviors conflict with each other. To alleviate this discomfort, individuals may engage in rationalization or cognitive reevaluation to justify their actions and reconcile inconsistencies.
In the context of the observed phenomenon, individuals may rationalize their participation in collective actions by minimizing the significance of their dissenting views or attributing their behavior to external pressures or situational factors.

Understanding the discrepancy between individual dissent and collective action highlights the complexities of social influence and identity dynamics. Recognizing this phenomenon prompts reflection on the balance between individual autonomy and group conformity in shaping behavior.
Encouraging critical self-reflection and fostering environments that value diversity of thought and expression can mitigate the pressures of conformity and promote authentic engagement within social groups.

Comment: I must say this is an excellent answer and silent dissent is an interesting concept. I like how you mention emergent phenomena. I think the phenomenon I'm interested in is one. But you also don't seem to name the phenomenon where the social consensus that emerges is contrary to the majority individual opinion. I think I am just going to refer to it as a paradoxical consensus.

Comment: Since this answer is AI generated without proper reference, it goes [against this site's policies](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/ai-policy).

Answer (score 2):

Disliking something about the social environment, but going along with it to avoid negative consequences such as conflict or disapproval is called "pragmatism", "being realistic", or more specifically, "going along to get along". No society can possibly be set up that doesn't have aspects that certain members of the society don't like, so inevitably, there will have to be some people who must choose between going along to get along, or rebelling. If enough people rebel, it can lead to social change, but the new rules usually have just as many or more dissatisfied people as the original rules, so there is no net benefit to justify the turmoil. People in general only think of their own circumstances and how the social rules effect themselves, not what purposes the rules might serve.

Comment: Dissenting or 'rebelling' can be quite civilised though, like with Greta Thunberg and/or environmental shareholder activists. Interestingly, change is this arena is significantly coming from direct *legal* challenges to government bypassing whatever is the population's majority opinion, yielding to rationality.

Comment: #derailing. This is not the place to have this conversation. Comments are being flagged.

Comment: @JuliusH., does "derailing" mean that someone is saying something that goes against the approved narrative?

Comment: I appreciate your answer but I don't think you quite understand what I refer too. In my scenario there is no minority that would rebel against a majority. If anything, to approximate it would be a majority rebelling against a minority. I am describing a situation in which the vast majority of the members of a social group in social life espouse values that contradict the ones they have privately and might even espouse to trusted other members of the group. The term false consensus approaches what I mean, but in a false consensus one can still openly dissent but just note they are compromising.

Answer (score 2):

If collective action is read within the context of political philosophy, then there is a term that fits: [dissent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dissent). From WP:

> Dissent is an opinion, philosophy or sentiment of non-agreement or opposition to a prevailing idea or policy enforced under the authority of a government, political party or other entity or individual. A dissenting person may be referred to as a dissenter.

And if the majority doesn't act in a way to stifle dissent, then that is called [tolerance (SEP)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/toleration/). If dissent is translated into political action legally, it is often called advocacy or [lobbying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lobbying), and if it crosses the line into illegality it might be characterized on a moralistic range from [civil disobedience](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civil_disobedience) to [terrorism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terrorism). A society that is broadly amenable to dissent and civil disobedience is called [liberal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberalism), and on the opposite side of the spectrum, is [totalitarianism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totalitarianism). Western Europe is largely considered liberal, for instance, and places like North Korea are considered totalitarian.